# Add non-steam games more than 1 folder deep in bulk

Tags: steam

I hope my question makes sense as-is - if not let me elaborate a bit.

When I click "add non-steam game", I get a big list of potential games it wants to suggest.  It looks like it is doing a recursive search for EXEs 1 folder deep.  I guess this because it seems to find most of my games but not the ones that have their executable in a subdirectory like "games\binaries".

Is there a way to tell Steam to search deeper, possibly via a setting I'm missing or the registry?  I have a lot of older games that I want to add.

edit:  my directory theory was wrong.  Some games that don't appear in the list have their EXE in the first folder (e.g. c:\games\Fallout3).

Comment: You can also manually select the exes, instead of just choosing from the list.

Comment: I know, but I want them to show up in the list so it doesn't take so long.

Comment: Alright, I figured it was something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button: Add non-Steam game, Steam searches the Registry for Entries. then all registered Programs that are not yet added to steam are shown in that window.

Steam does not support non-registered (not properly installed) Games unlike to other game-overlays (xFire, Gameranger). in these overlays you have to add the path to a game manually if it is not installed with registry-entry.

Your request is simply not possible with Steam.

Comment: @Killith: FYI:you can add Registry Entries for any Application, even after installation. maybe this will help showing the Games in the Steam-Window, but i do not know for sure

Comment: Hey buddy, appreciate the tip.  However, this defeats the purpose, as it is more time consuming than actually adding the steam game.

I suppose if I had thousands of games, and I could pick the files out with a regex or something, I could write a program to add them to the registry, but I don't have thousands of games. :)

Answer (score 2):

#### It is possible

It is possible *now* but it didn't use to be.

While having the `Add a Non-Steam Game` window open, there will be a button that says `Browse...`, click that and it will open a Windows Explorer window that allows you to choose a program from anywhere on any of your hard drives.

Comment: Don't worry about the age of the question. Answering questions with outdated answers is actually quite beneficial to the site. No need to be shy about it.